# Returning a column value from a table in dataset

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net

I have a dataset with two tables.I want to get the value of first column from second table and initialize it to an int variable.
The name of that column was CONTACT_ID

I tried like this.

```
  int Contract_id = Convert.ToInt32(dsDiscounts.Tables[1].Columns[0]);
```

but it was showing an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataColumn' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.

can anyone help me please

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`dsDiscounts.Tables[1].Columns[0]` returns column definition (data type, caption, etc defined by [DataColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.aspx) instance). Of course column definition conversion to integer fails.

What you need is cell value from some row of table (assume first row). You should use [`Rows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection to get access to table rows. After you get required [`DataRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by it's index, you can access cells in row [by index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [column name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), column object, etc. E.g. getting first row's cell value by column name:

```
 dsDiscounts.Tables[1].Rows[0]["CONTACT_ID"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
int Contract_id = Convert.ToInt32(dsDiscounts.Tables[1].Rows[0]["CONTACT_ID"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static T SafeGet<T>(this System.Data.DataSet dataset, string tableindex, int RowCount, string Nameofcolumn)
{
    try
    {
        return dataset.Tables[tableindex].Rows[RowCount].IsNull(Nameofcolumn) == false ?
            (T)Convert.ChangeType(dataset.Tables[tableindex].Rows[RowCount][Nameofcolumn], typeof(T))
            : default(T);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```